# Going live with Paypal - difference between REST API app and CLASSIC API app?

Tags: android, ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Our app uses PayPal to make payments for a service through our iOS and Android apps. We are preparing for submission and need to switch from sandbox to live. However the Paypal documentation is quite unclear!

Our app is listed under REST API apps (rather than Classic API apps). Is this ok if all we intend to do is take payment via Paypal account and direct/credit card?

The process of registering a REST API app is quite different to registering a CLASSIC API app. If we want to register as a CLASSIC API app then Paypal require legally recognised documents and an apk/ipa for testing. I imagine that will add significant time to our project as it will need to be reviewed manually (which we can't afford the time cost).

So are we safe to continue with the REST API app? We've implemented the latest Paypal mobile sdk's into the apps and have a fairly straightforward scenario (accept non-recurring Paypal and credit card payments).

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that REST is built around [oauth](/questions/tagged/oauth) and is designed for environments where you have to have that feature (i.e. some mobile platforms natively support it).

Classic can be run with either [soap](/questions/tagged/soap) or name-value pairs(NVP). It contains a much simpler authorization scheme but Classic has been around longer and has a number of calls that REST does not yet support. Some notable exceptions include

- [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/) (send money to a PayPal account via API)
- [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/gs_AdaptiveAccounts/) (split payments between multiple accounts)

Now, you tagged this [[image]android](/questions/tagged/android). So if you want to publish your app in Google Play or Amazon Appstore, understand that you may not accept some payments within your app via PayPal without violating their TOS. Both Google Play and Appstore require you to use their payment systems for virtual goods. From the [Google Play TOS](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6151557)

> Developers charging for apps and downloads from Google Play must do so by using Google Play’s payments system. If your app offers virtual goods or currencies to be used within the app, it must use Google Play’s in-app billing service as the method of payment.

Comment: Thank you, Machavity. Based on your answer and my research, I think (in my case) we're ok to proceed with REST. The payment is for a service rather than a virtual good or currency, so we should be all clear in that respect too.